# How to show table if it has data from api otherwise show other div

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular 6 application. I have a table showing data from a web api, also I have some `ngIf` containers. One shows a message if the web api data is empty. The other one should show the table if there is data coming back in. My current code does not work:

**.ts file**

```
  public errorApi = false;
  public tableShow = false;

ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getIncidents(this.customer_id).subscribe((data) => {
      this.loading = true;
      this.data = data.result;
      this.loading = false;
      console.log('Result - ', data);
      console.log('data is received');

      this.errorApi = data.result == null || data.result === 0 || data.result.length === 0;
      this.tableShow = this.data && this.data.result;
      }) 
    }
}
```

**html**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="errorApi">
        <div class="column col-12 text-center pt-10 pb-10">
        <div class="empty">
            <div class="empty-icon">
              <i class="icon icon-people"></i>
            </div>
            <p class="empty-title h5">There are no incidents to display</p>
            <div class="empty-action">
              <button class="btn btn-primary">Create an incident</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
      </ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="tableshow">
       <table></table>
      </ng-container>
```

Comment: When you are doing `this.data = data.result` why are you checking `this.data && this.data.result` ?

Comment: If there is data or is null

Comment: I guess you should only be checking `this.tableShow = this.data` as `this.data` already has `data.result` ? Or did you mean `this.data.length` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the data variable directly to check if it has data or not.

This checks if you have data in the `data` array. If it has, it will display the table but if it's empty array or null then it will display the error.

Define your data variable in the `ts` first:
`data = [];`

```
<div *ngIf="!data.length > 0">
    <div class="column col-12 text-center pt-10 pb-10">
        <div class="empty">
            <div class="empty-icon">
                <i class="icon icon-people"></i>
            </div>
            <p class="empty-title h5">There are no incidents to display</p>
            <div class="empty-action">
              <button class="btn btn-primary">Create an incident</button>
            </div>
       </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="data.length > 0">
   <p>Table Data here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @MaihanNijat in order to avoid undefined you have to initialize `data` while declare `data = []` in ts file. Right now angular template doesnot aware if data is going to be an {} or []

Comment: My data is defined in the .ts file as `public data: any;`

Comment: Still get that error: error Cannot read property 'length' of undefined?

Comment: Ok the errors have gone, but the error message comes flashes in even if there is data?

Comment: @MaihanNijat Which condition were you referring to?

Answer (score 2):

Try *else* in ngIf statement

```
<ng-container *ngIf="errorApi else apiTable">
        <div class="column col-12 text-center pt-10 pb-10">
        <div class="empty">
            <div class="empty-icon">
              <i class="icon icon-people"></i>
            </div>
            <p class="empty-title h5">There are no incidents to display</p>
            <div class="empty-action">
              <button class="btn btn-primary">Create an incident</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
      </ng-container>

<ng-container #apiTable>
       <table></table>
      </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `else` from `*ngIf` directive:

```
*ngIf="errorApi; else apiTable"
```

Comment: In the original question there is no "apiTable"

Answer (score 0):

```
public data: any;
public loading: boolean;

private subscription: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
   this.loading = true;
   this.subscription = this.service.getIncidents(this.customer_id)
   .subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.loading = false;

      // Because you have no error logic in your service
      If (data.result //&& any other validation on the data: {}) {
          this.data = data.result;

          console.log('Result - ', data);
          console.log('data is received');
      } else {
        this.errorApi = true;
      } 
    });
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
   this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

And in your html you can use `ng-template`:

```
<ng-template *ngIf="data && !loading; else errorTemplate">...</ng-template>
<ng-template #errorTemplate>...</ng-template>
```

Obviously, accommodate for your validation on the data: {} but this should provide you some ideas.

Comment: Ideally you should implement your service to return the data as valid and use (error: any) => {} to account for the errors you may encounter. That way you don't have to check twice for the data {} and you can simply use this.data as a check in your DOM as oppose to all the other conditions on the object you are currently using.